# Resizing bootstrap form box not working when <span> tag is removed

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to resize a form box using .col-md-12. It works fine if I keep the code inside the span tag as it is, but if I take it off (and I want to, because I need to remove that button) it stops working. In this scenario the form box will maintain some kind of default size, no matter which value is inserted after -md.
Could anyone give some help? If it matters, this HTML file is part of the viewer of a project using laravel framework.

```
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">{{ 'name' }}</label>          
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="{{ $name }}">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ url('path', $id) }}" title="{{ 'edit' }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that I understood your question right, just add the btn class to the span tag and remove the a tag.

```
<span class="input-group-btn btn">
    <!-- removed button -->
</span>
```